# How do we get Dintinct Field Name (not the field values) from Opensearch/ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

How do we get Dintinct Field Name (not the field values) from Opensearch/ElasticSearch?

{"K1": "V1",
"K2": "V2",
}

Response should be {K1, K2}

Could not find any anything equivalent in ES documentation

How do we get Dintinct Field Name (not the field values) from Opensearch/ElasticSearch?

Comment: Simply get the mapping of your index?

Answer (score 0):

On probably every version of Elasticsearch you can use the [index mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/indices-get-field-mapping.html). The result will be of the form

```
{"index_name": { "mappings": { "field1": {...}, "field2": {...}}}}
```